# how to show all selected item(s) into another activity like in shopping cart's viewcart activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget, android-listview

I am fetching data into listview using JSON, i am providing facility to user click on any of the item listview row, and will be able to view that selected item into another activity, still i am showing only single item added by user to cart in viewcart activity, now i want to show all the selected item(s) in viewcart activity, like: as in shoppingcart's viewcart activity form, here i am just showing Title and Cost, which i am fetching into singleitemactivity by using listviewitem row click

SingleItem Code:-

```
    public class SingleMenuItem extends Activity{
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "imageUri";
private EditText edit_qty_code;
private TextView txt_total;
private TextView text_cost_code;
private double itemamount = 0;
private double itemquantity = 0;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);
    TextView txtcost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    TextView txtheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtheader.setText(title);
    txtcost.setText(cost);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);

    text_cost_code = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    edit_qty_code = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.single_qty);
    txt_total=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.single_total);

    itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
    txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemamount));

    edit_qty_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         itemquantity=Double.parseDouble(edit_qty_code.getText().toString());
         itemamount=Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());
         txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemquantity*itemamount));
    }
    });             
     ImageButton addToCartButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_add);
    addToCartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {    

        Intent in = new Intent
          (SingleMenuItem.this, com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.FinalOrder.class);
        in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE)); 
        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_COST));
        startActivity(in);

            // Close the activity
            //  finish();
        }
    });    
}}
```

FinalOrder Code:-

```
public class FinalOrder extends Activity
{
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);  

        Intent in = getIntent();

        String title1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
        String cost1 = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);

        TextView txttitle1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        TextView txtcost1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_cost);

        txttitle1.setText(title1);
        txtcost1.setText(cost1);  
    }
}
```

Comment: where you filled the data in `itemsList` It is empty. That is why it throughs exception.

Comment: could you pls tell me, in singleitem activity i am fetching data using itemlistview click, and now i just want to show these data like:- only title and cost to viewcart activity so am i need to use itemslist or not?

Comment: you want to send the data you receive in `SingleMenuItem` to `FinalOrder` Activity? then just do this `in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE));

        in.putExtra(KEY_COST, getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_COST));`

Comment: your logcat says indexOutOfBound exeception so itemList has no data.. you are not filling data and just using index 0 so app crash at index 0

Comment: Mohsin i will try and then get back to you

Comment: Thanks a lot, mohsin, i hope you will help me, now i need to show all the selected item(s) data by user in a session, like here we are showing only single one, but now i want to show these two details i.e. Title and Cost for all selected items, so please tell me what i need to write to do that

Comment: like: ViewCart form in shopping carts

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putString(KEY_TITLE , "Title");
    prefsEditor.putString(KEY_COST , "cost");
    prefsEditor.commit();
```

OR use a class with static variables so that you can pass it on

You can use setters to set the data

```
SomeClass.setTitle(String title){
KEY_TITLE = title;
}

SomeClass.setCost(String cost){
KEY_COST = cost;
}
```

And from the activity where you need it you can get it using getters

```
    SomeClass.getTitle();
    SomeClass.getCost();
```

Comment: @Moshin Bundles are not working for him, you care to suggest a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Use `Intent in = getIntent().getextras();` instead `Intent in = getIntent();`

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras();` returns an `Intent` ?

Comment: yup this will returns Intent with some values which was sent in bundle.

Comment: Hi to all viewers and readers, i have edited my question and code please help

Answer (score 0):

```
itemsList.get(position);
```

here is the problem. the size of `itemsList` is none and you are trying to get the item index of 0. So the android gives you the indexoutofbound exception.

first 
check whether the size of itemsList is greater than 0 then try to get the item from the `itemsList`.

eg:-

```
if(itemsList != null && itemsList.size > 0)
{
  HashMap<String, String> map = itemsList.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using data within two activities, you can achieve it by `Bundle`, if global usage of data, you can also use your getter setter file extending `Application` data and registering in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

First check the `extras` for `null` reference like:

```
String extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String newString;
if(extras == null) {
    newString= null;
} else {
    newString= extras.getString("MY_STRING");
}
```